# Design pattern for static base constructor that calls static method in final class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, static, virtual-functions

How can I achieve the following design using C++11:

```
class Consumer : Base<Consumer>
{
    // different consumers will have different methods (of the same signature)
    void Foo(){...}
    void Bar(){...}
    : // etc.

    static void override
    register_all () {
        register_method<&Consumer::Foo>("foo");
        register_method<&Consumer::Bar>("bar");
        : // etc.
    }
    :
}

template<typename T>
class Base
{
    static 
    Base() { 
        register(); 
    }

    virtual static void
    register_all(){ };

    using F = void(T::*)();

    template<F f>
    static void 
    register_method(std::string name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

...?

Note that I'm doing two illegal things:

- I am using a static constructor (not allowed) on the base class
- I am using virtual static function (also not allowed)

NOTE: Registration of methods needs to occur only once, before the first instance is accessed (it will populate a static C-function-pointer table).

Finally, is there any better technique I could be using, some way of somehow tagging or marking methods that need to be registered, and save the consumer the trouble of having to manually register them in a separate function?

Comment: `register` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: I don't get what you're doing here. There are too many imaginary constructs at work that make it hard to follow the overall point.

Comment: Are the names of the methods you want to register known and globally fixed, or does every derived class decide itself what to register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe regular [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) will work just fine. This gets rid of both the `virtual` and the `static`. Using an [`std::once_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) in combination with [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) will allow you to only call the function once -- mimicking the effects of a 'static constructor'. It just requires a little bit of messing around.

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
struct Base {
    Base() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->register_all();
    }

    using F = void(T::*)();

    template<F f>
    void register_method(const char* str) {
        // ...
        std::cout << "registered " << str << '\n';
    }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived> {
private:
    static std::once_flag flag_;
    void implementation() {
        register_method<&Derived::foo>("foo");
        register_method<&Derived::bar>("bar");
    }
public:
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}

    void register_all() {
        std::call_once(flag_, [this]{ implementation(); });
    }
};

std::once_flag Derived::flag_;

int main() {
    Derived x;
    Derived y;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/441e177ebfcf242c)

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of "one-time registration" -- I've put a note in the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Pi You might be able to do some trickery with [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) since the syntax proposed is kind of impossible (can't have static member functions that rely on non-static member functions).

Comment: Sorry, I made to many errors with the initial pseudocode :/ I have added the necessary static-s. BTW, CRTP solves the static override issue nicely -- thanks!

Comment: @Pi I've updated the answer to showcase what I mean with `std::call_once`.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified Rapptz's answer to move all the machinery back into the base class:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52fd723e905333c6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
struct Base {
    Base() {
        std::call_once(flag_, T::register_all );
    }

    using F = void(T::*)();

    template<F f>
    static void register_method(const char* str) {
        // ...
        std::cout << "registered " << str << '\n';
    }
public:
    static std::once_flag flag_;
};

// have to initialise static-s outside class...
template<typename T>
std::once_flag Base<T>::flag_{};
```

...

```
struct Derived1 : Base<Derived1> {
public:
    static void register_all() {
        std::cout << "D1" << '\n';
        register_method<&Derived1::foo>("foo");
        register_method<&Derived1::bar>("bar");
    }
public:
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

struct Derived2 : Base<Derived2> {
public:
    static void register_all() {
        std::cout << "D2" << '\n';
        register_method<&Derived2::woot>("woot");
    }
public:
    void woot() {}
};
```

...

```
int main() {
    Derived1 x;
    Derived1 y;

    Derived2 z;
}
```

EDIT: strangely I need to initialise my flag with {} but Rapptz didn't.  Why is this?

EDIT2: this code fails on ideone, because ideone doesn't use -pthread compiler flag. Using a simpler 'static bool first=true; if(first){first = false;...} construct would do the trick as c++11 stipulates that initialisation of static variables be thread safe.

Comment: "*EDIT: strangely I need to initialise my flag with {} but Rapptz didn't. Why is this?*" Because of a GCC bug.